# Docker: Jar: not found

Tags: docker, jar, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and working on developing the Docker image for our application in Ubuntu environment.

However, the below command is not working when executed from within the Dockerfile/ from within the docker-entrypoint file.

command: “jar xf ./abc.ear”

_/docker-entrypoint.sh: 69: /docker-entrypoint.sh: jar: not found**

I verified and ear file is present in the directory.

I tried passing the full path to ear or passed the full path to Jar command, however, no success.

Please help.

...............

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

start=$(date +'%s')
# Setting Environment Variables
DEPLOY_DIR=/home/docker/xyz
SCRIPT_DIR=/usr/local/src

if [ "$(ls -A $DEPLOY_DIR/Install 2> /dev/null)" = "" ]; then
    echo "The directory $DEPLOY_DIR/Install is empty."

# Fetch Installable from Artifactory
    echo "[INFO] Extracting files from Artifactory"
    mkdir -p $DEPLOY_DIR 
    cd $DEPLOY_DIR 
    wget -nv ArtifactoryPath 
    unzip "123.zip" -d $DEPLOY_DIR 

# Install
    cd $DEPLOY_DIR/ 
    Install command

# Configure JAVA
    echo "[INFO] Linking java folder" 
    ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle $DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jdk 

# Explode ear and war files
    echo "[INFO] Explode ear and war files\n" 
    cd $DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jboss/deployments
    ls -al
    mv "$WFC_DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jboss/deployments/abc.ear" "$WFC_DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jboss/deployments/abc-old.ear"
    mkdir -p abc.ear 
    cd $DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jboss/deployments/abc.ear
    echo $PWD
    mv "$DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jboss/deployments/abc-old.ear" ./
    ls -al
    jar xvf "$DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jboss/deployments/abc.ear/abc-old.ear"
    rm -rf $DEPLOY_DIR/Install/jboss/deployments/abc.ear/abc-old.ear

else
    echo "$DEPLOY_DIR/Install is not empty."
fi
```

Comment: What is `jar` command? Maybe you meant `java -jar`?

Comment: Yes...I tried it as "java -jar xf abc.ear"...even then it didn't work.

Comment: Can you add more stuff about you docker-entrypoint.sh ?

Comment: Did you got the same error with `java -jar`? Have you tried `/usr/bin/java -jar`?

Comment: Please refer to the original post for docker-entrypoint.sh details.

Comment: @Sergii Bishyr: Yes, I tried it and getting same error: /docker-entrypoint.sh: 69: /docker-entrypoint.sh: /usr/bin/java: not found

Comment: What is your base docker image?